# htaccess redirect from a friendly url to one with parameters

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to create a rewrite rule that redirects vistors from one url to another on an Ecwid store, but I can't seem to get the syntax correct.

I'd like to redirect visitors from :

```
http://domain.ca/category/#######
```

to

```
http://domain.ca/products/#!/~/category/id=#######&offset=0&sort=normal
```

I've tried several variations below, but all generate a 500 Internal Server Error

```
Rewrite Rule ^/category/(.*)$ http://domain.ca/products/#!/~/category/id=$1&offset=0&sort=normal [R=301,L]
Rewrite Rule ^/category/(.*)$ http://domain.ca/products/#\!/~/category/id\=$1&offset\=0&sort\=normal [R=301,L]
Rewrite Rule ^/category/(.*)$ /products/#\!/~/category/id\=$1&offset\=0&sort\=normal [R=301,L]
Rewrite Rule ^/category/(.+)$ http://domain.ca/products/#!/~/category/id=$1&offset=0&sort=normal [R=301,L]
```

Here are the existing rewrite's in the htaccess file, using anubhava's example below

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^category/(.+)$ /products/#!/~/category/id=$1&offset=0&sort=normal [R=301,L,NE]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have syntax issues. Use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^category/(.+)$ /products/#!/~/category/id=$1&offset=0&sort=normal [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: this is redirecting me from domain.ca/category/4619309 to domain.ca/4619309. I've editing the original post to include the entire contents of the htacesss in case there's a conflict with an existing rule

Comment: On a somewhat related note, what does L,NE represent?

Comment: Try updated code now. `NE` flag means `no escape` to avoid escaping special characters in target URI.

Comment: Thanks, the edited version works! Also what does the (.+)$ represent? I'd guess take any number of characters and dump them into the $ variable?

Comment: Yes that is correct. `(.+)` is called capturing group to use it as `$1` later